# jquery dialog moves with mouse

Tags: jquery

I have a jquery dialog defined as so:

```
<div id="rankdialog"><p>Content</p></div>
```

And to open the dialog I have:

HTML:

```
<p id="openrankdialog">Click Here for more info</p>
```

JS:

```
$("#rankdialog").dialog({autoOpen : false, modal : false});

$("#openrankdialog").on('click', function()
{
    $("#rankdialog").dialog("open");
    return false;
});
```

However when the dialog is opened it automatically moves when the mouse moves, meaning the user cannot move their mouse cursor to the X. The only way to close the dialog is to press the Escape key.

How do I prevent this?

I created a fiddle with replica code and this error does not occur. On my page I have an error in console log:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'unbind' of undefined
```

This occurs on mouse up.

Comment: Can you reproduce this in a jsFiddle?

Comment: I created a jsfiddle but the issue does not occur there. I have 2 exception is console log though. Updated my answer

Comment: Well, if you can't reproduce the issue in the jsfiddle it should be obvious that your problem is elsewhere.

Comment: jquery version in 1.8.6, jquery-ui version is 1.11.3, cause?

Comment: Cause was incompatible jquery and jquery-ui version. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

http://jsfiddle.net/125ckp9z/

Here is the link to the fiddle, and since you did not put any markup:

```
<button id="openrankdialog">Open</button>
<div id="rankdialog"><p>Content</p></div>
```

This is the fiddle url and the correct way of doing it. Please share more of your code in case you are still facing the same problem, since the underlying problem could be somewhere else